# Ruby: Return data grouped by multiple columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying group data for a web service.

The web service is running on Ruby on Rails and I'm working in my API controller (lets call it the index action of my projects_controller.

The table schema looks like this (the data types and example has been changed for NDA reasons). Unfortunately, the example here suggests that I break employee and projects into different tables, but please overlook that for now. This is the data that I am given:

```
COLUMNS:
employee, e_id, company, hire_date, project_name, project_due_date

ROWS:
John, 12345, XYZ, 01-01-2001, Project_A, 12-31-2012
John, 12345, XYZ, 01-01-2001, Project_B, 03-15-2013
John, 12345, XYZ, 01-01-2001, Project_C, 06-25-2013
Jane, 98765, XYZ, 05-22-2003, Project_Q, 01-15-2013
Jane, 98765, XYZ, 05-22-2003, Project_W, 02-25-2013
Jane, 98765, XYZ, 05-22-2003, Project_E, 08-01-2013
```

In order to reduce data transfer, I would like to return the above as follows:

```
[
    {
        "employee":"John",
        "e_id":"12345",
        "company":"XYZ",
        "hire_date":"01-01-2001",
        "projects":[
                     { "project_name":"Project_A", "project_due_date":"12-31-2012" },
                     { "project_name":"Project_B", "project_due_date":"03-15-2013" },
                     { "project_name":"Project_C", "project_due_date":"06-25-2013" }
                   ]
    },
    {
        "employee":"Jane",
        "e_id":"98765",
        "company":"XYZ",
        "hire_date":"05-22-2003",
        "projects":[
                     { "project_name":"Project_Q", "project_due_date":"01-15-2013" },
                     { "project_name":"Project_W", "project_due_date":"02-25-2013" },
                     { "project_name":"Project_E", "project_due_date":"08-01-2013" }
                   ]
    }
]
```

I can't seem to figure out the best way to group my SQL query results (rows) into the organized hash(es) that I have in the ideal data.  I imagine I need some .each and hashes to post-process the data returned by my SQL call, but I can't seem to figure out the "Ruby" way (I'm also not a seasoned Ruby developer, so any reference links would also be appreciated so I can read up on the solution).

How can I accomplish this?

[EDIT]

I am performing a SQL query on the Project object. My controller is as follows:

```
def index
   sql = "SELECT employee, e_id, company, hire_date, project_name, project_due_date
     FROM projects
     AND created_at = (SELECT created_at FROM projects ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)
     ORDER BY company, employee, project_due_date"

   result = Project.find_by_sql(sql)
   respond_with(result)
end
```

The data I am getting back is a bunch of Project objects in the following format

RUBY DEBUGGER:

```
(rdb:2) result
[#<Project employee: "John", e_id: 12345, company: "XYZ", hire_date: "01-01-2001", project_name: "Project_A", project_due_date: "12-31-2012">,
 #<Project employee: "John", e_id: 12345, company: "XYZ", hire_date: "01-01-2001", project_name: "Project_B", project_due_date: "03-15-2013">,
 #<Project employee: "John", e_id: 12345, company: "XYZ", hire_date: "01-01-2001", project_name: "Project_C", project_due_date: "06-25-2013">,
 #<Project employee: "Jane", e_id: 98765, company: "XYZ", hire_date: "05-22-2003", project_name: "Project_Q", project_due_date: "01-15-2013">,
 #<Project employee: "Jane", e_id: 98765, company: "XYZ", hire_date: "05-22-2003", project_name: "Project_W", project_due_date: "02-25-2013">,
 #<Project employee: "Jane", e_id: 98765, company: "XYZ", hire_date: "05-22-2003", project_name: "Project_E", project_due_date: "08-01-2013">]
```

[EDIT 2]

I know I can resolve this problem in a very naive, non-Ruby way, but I'd like to know the proper way to get it working.  A basic solution could consist of iterating through the result array and parsing out the data row by row, saving the employee data to a temp hash and their project data to an array of hashes.  When the iteration comes to a new employee, save the data for the previous employee data in an array and reset the temp array/hashes for the next employee.  Very ugly, but very possible.

However, there MUST be a Ruby way.  Please help!

Comment: Is the SQL result a single text? What exactly is the Ruby object that you have?

Comment: Are you using Rails or another framework? Which DB? Any ORM, or do you want a solution with a plain SQL query? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @sawa I added a section to the bottom of the original post "[EDIT]" with more information. Hopefully that clarifies a bit more.

Comment: @padde the web service API is written using Ruby on Rails.  The DB is SQLITE3.  See my [EDIT] in the original post.  Hopefully that will describe my problem a bit better.  I'm not entirely sure what the best solution is for this (in fact I'm totally stuck right now). If this is resolved using pure SQL that would be fine. I would prefer a solution that provides the fastest response time since this is an API that will be called from mobile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce the grouped data in the requested form:

```
grouped_data = data.group_by do |project|
  [project.employee, project.e_id, project.company, project.hire_date]
end.map do |k, v|
  { 
    "employee"  => k[0],
    "e_id"      => k[1],
    "company"   => k[2],
    "hire_date" => k[3],

    "projects" => v.map do |p|
      {
        "project_name"     => p.project_name,
        "project_due_date" => p.project_due_date
      }
    end
  }
end
```

And finally use `to_json` to produce the JSON formatted version, e.g.:

```
grouped_data.to_json
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Don, however the result is not exactly what I'm looking for. Please see the expected JSON result in the 2nd code block in my original post.

Comment: OK - I've updated the answer to produce the result in the requested form.

Comment: Worked exactly as expected and I actually learnt something for the next time.  Thanks so much.